# How to get current AppInfo in UWP environment

Tags: c#, uwp

How can I get the current [AppInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo) of the running UWP application? I could not find any accessible constructor or static function to get this information.

Comment: What Information of the class do you need? Maybe you could use the Windows.ApplicationModel.Package instead?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But the comment stating to use package instead solved my problem. I needed some information that were both included in package and appinfo. So i used package as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could get [`App​Diagnostic​Info`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appdiagnosticinfo) of all uwp apps that are running by the following code.

```
var list = await App​Diagnostic​Info.RequestInfoAsync();
```

And then you could get [`AppInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInfo) from each item in the App​Diagnostic​Info list.

```
foreach (var diagnosticinfo in list)
{
    info = diagnosticinfo.AppInfo;
}
var id = info.Id;
```

Please note that you need to declare the following capabilities in the Package.appxmainfest.

```
<Package
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" 
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  <Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="appDiagnostics" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your device is updated to Windows10 Creators Update version.
Firstly, you should add Capability **appDiagnostics** to Package.appxmanifest. Directly to modify the code of the file.

```
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"     xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="appDiagnostics"/>
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Then in the main code, get current package by matching the PackageFamilyName.

```
var list = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync();
var currentPackage = list.Where(o => o.AppInfo.PackageFamilyName == Package.Current.Id.FamilyName).FirstOrDefault();
if (currentPackage != null)
{
    AppInfo currentAppInfo = currentPackage.AppInfo;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But the comment stating to use package instead solved my problem. I needed some information that were both included in package and appinfo. So i used package as solution.