# How to get running application name in UWP?

Tags: c++, uwp

I have a C++ dll that is used by different UWP apps. Inside my dll I want to get the name of the running app. Standard winapi functions seem to not work, because they return exe names of some "wrappers" (e.g. ApplicationFrameHost.exe...).

Comment: Probably related [How to get current AppInfo in UWP environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299452/how-to-get-current-appinfo-in-uwp-environment).

Comment: @VTT yeah, but I want to get the info from native code

Comment: Those are UWP APIs that are available from native code.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [[UWP]How to get running application name in UWP?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/582b4369-a9aa-4caf-b01e-3c7fc9ec0b67/uwphow-to-get-running-application-name-in-uwp?forum=wpdevelop), [Azat Tazayan](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/azat%20tazayan/?ws=usercard-mini) says you can like below to retrieve name

```
 Package^ package = Package::Current; 
 PackageId^ packageId = package->Id;
 String^ name= packageId->Name ;
```

But the above code is just return name of Package, if your exe file name is different with package name, above code is return incorrect name.

So you must use some code like below (based on [How do I get the name of the current executable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616715/1539100))

```cpp
    char filename[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD size = GetModuleFileNameA(nullptr, filename, MAX_PATH);
    std::reverse_iterator<char*> it = std::find_if(std::rbegin(filename), std::rend(filename), [](const char c) { return c == '\\'; });
    const std::string exeName(it.base());
```