# Why do I get compiler error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I am setting a variable equal to 'AppInfo.DisplayInfo' and get the compiler error. Note, none of my classes or methods are 'static.' Therefore, the pther answers do not apply.

I have tried to create a an object of the class AppInfo but it also had a compiler error.
`enter code here`

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
public class CLog
{
    public void Start ()
    {
        AppDisplayInfo AppData = AppInfo.DisplayInfo; // Compiler error 
    }
}
```

Comment: `AppInfo` is not static, either. You need an instance of it to get the `DisplayInfo` property.

Comment: What was the compiler error when you tried to create an instance of `AppInfo`?

Comment: I tried adding a line: "AppInfo tInfo = new AppInfo();" Got error that constructor does not take 0 args. Online docs for AppInfo have no info on constructor.

Comment: Here is link to online doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo

Answer (score 2):

Static properties are referred to by using the name of the class, followed by the property name, which is what you're doing with `AppInfo.DisplayInfo`.

The error is telling you that that the [`AppInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo) class does not have a static property called `DisplayInfo`.

You can only access the [`DisplayInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinfo.displayinfo) property on an *instance* of the `AppInfo` class.

If you want to get the `AppInfo` object for the current app, then refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320199/1202807). And as mentioned in a comment on that question, you can find the description and logo for the app from [`Package.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.package.current) (*that's* a static property), which might be easier, if that's all you need.